# Sharepoint 2013 Search Tagged Site Pages

Tags: 2013, search, keyword

Hi I'm fairly new to the search in Sharepoint;

I have a website with many sub-sites and pages;

I have created a search result which searches just our courses that we run, these are site pages not in a list;

Is there a way to somehow add a tag or keyword to a page and set up the search to only search the pages with that tag, keyword or category?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use a custom content type for my pages (derived from base page content type). You can add any custom site columns you may need to the custom content type. Category and Tag for instance. Once you've created a few pages from the new custom content type (and populated the category and tag fields) and then run a crawl you should be able to start searching using these new fields. Searching by field values requires that you have a managed property mapped to your crawled property. This usually happens by default for new custom site columns but if not you will need to create this mapping yourself and then run another crawl. Then you can use it in your search query, such as:

Category:sharepoint

This searches for items whose Category managed property contains the word sharepoint.